# How to inherit default textbox style in wpf datagrid?

Tags: wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I have a `TextBox`  in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` in a WPF datagrid.It doesn't inherit the look and feel of the datagrid itself.For example it doesn't show the alternating color, when a row is selected or edited.

```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ...}" />                          
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It looks like the style of a default textbox overrides that of the `DataGrid`.Is there any way to use the datagrids style?

Comment: What style `TextBox` by default? Your style or system?

Comment: I dont undrestand what you mean,Textbox in the DataGridTemplateColumn should have the same style as text boxes inside DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: No it should not. When you specify a forced `TextBox` in `DataTemplate` you automatically overwrites the default `DataGridCell` style for the `DataGrid`. You need to establish a single style for `DataGridCell`, then it will be all one style for `TextBox` (in `DataGridTemplateColumn` and in `DataGridTextColumn`). When set a uniform style for `DataGridCell`, it will still need to set the style for `DataGridRow`, because selects the row will not work. In any case, it is better to take a predefined style for `DataGrid` and remake it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case:-

```
 <DataGrid Background="White" AlternatingRowBackground="#BCD2EE"
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
....
.....
....
    </DataGrid>
```

This is what I used once you can set property according to your requirements.

This Might help ..:)